# Android app advice, multiple intent services?

Tags: android, intentservice

My app has a UI and a connection is made to a bluetooth device which is periodically sending barcode scan data to my app. I then want to cache this data in a sqlite db and have another process push this data up to a web server.

I have managed to get the UI and bluetooth scan process separated by using an Intent Service for the scanner component... The thread in the intent service connects to the bluetooth device and loops endlessly pulling in new scan data as it comes... communicating with the UI via broadcast messages as it needs to.

So now I need to handle storing the data in a sqlite db and pushing it up to the Internet.

I'm thinking I can insert a db row directly in the intent service loop I already have working for the bluetooth data... would I do that by firing of an async task or something like that?

Then, would I have a completely different intent service running and looping endlessly checking for new records to be processed and pushed up to my web server via an http post?

I guess the main reason I'm thinking of using intent services is that they seem to keep running even if I lock my phone and put it in my pocket... has worked so far for the bluetooth barcode scanner... can scan away happily with my phone locked and in my pocket.

I also need to handle the reality that internet won't always be available... hence the sqlite db... kind of like a safe buffer to store data until it can eventually be pushed up to the Web server.

Am I going down the right path? I'm really new to Android development and even after much research I'm still unsure about my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data or communicate from IntentService onHandleIntent() directly. You don't need to run it in separate thread, unless you want reading bluetooth to continue ASAP.

Handling everything in an infinite loop smells. Also keeping service alive depends on few factors. If IntentService dies, it won't be restored because by default IntentService.onStartCommand implicitly returns START_NOT_STICKY, or START_REDELIVER_INTENT if you call setIntentRedelivery(true) on this service. Check Service [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more info.

If you can scan bluetooth periodically then I would consider kind of scheduler. For that you would probably need to implement Service, not IntentService and handle background thread yourself. Alternatively, you could use a Timer. These are more hints, not ready solution. Since you asked about direction, I assume you will investigate solutions yourself.

Depending on handled data you could separate DB operations and network to separate services. Think about them as modules which are decoupled. You will benefit maintaing this code in the future and in case one service goes down due to any reason, the rest will keep working. It depends on data size because it's not a good practise to push heavy data between service/activities(data is serialised and deserialised every time it is sent).

If DB is just a buffer/queue then maybe use it directly after reading bluetooth data. In other words queue data for sending. Create second service for HTTP communications. Don't push entire data to second service, just inform it about(knock the door :)) and let HTTP service access DB by itself. I would wrap DB in ContentProvider and access it from services.

There are probably different techniques out there too, but that's what I thought about it in the first place.

Comment: Hey thanks for a your thoughts, very helpful! Sorry, pressed enter so comment submitted before I finished... I'm still typing!

Comment: Hey thanks for a your thoughts, very helpful! Yes I don't like the idea of an infinite loop either, seems crazy to me and from the world of PC .net programming if I did that then the process would consume 100% cpu!!! Not sure if it's the same in Android. The data can come in very frequently from the bluetooth device so I need to check for data quite often... and if I don't read it while having a connection to the device open it locks the device up... so I have to check frequently. But yes, I hate the idea of an infinite loop... I was hoping the bluetooth layer would have...(cont'd)

Comment: ... an event driven process, like in the world of .net we might have an event "onData()" which the bluetooth layer fires every time new data comes in but it doesn't seem to work that way in Android :(  I will definitely have the process pushing the data up to the web server running as a separate thread/service/something. .. for the reasons you already listed and mainly because in some cases there may be left over scans in the data base that need to be pushed up when there is no bluetooth device connected anymore. (cont'd)

Comment: ... I guess I'm still really confused about the way the UI and services/thread stuff works. It's very strange trying to work in an environment where the operating system can destroy parts of the application as it pleases!

Comment: Welcome to the mobile world. Think about it like a house full of guests(applications) where every guest would like to use a bathroom(System service/network/battery consumption) or any other room. They are not the owners so they must behave polite and may not abuse hospitality of the landlord(Android). On PC connected to power supply most users won't notice higher CPU or RAM consumption. On mobile it will be noticed immediately.

Comment: Love that analogy! :-)  It's a lot of fun and some interesting new challenges. I setup the bluetooth data read process using some code I scavenged off the internet (probably here on stackoverflow), it had the "while (true)" loop constantly looking for new data from the bluetooth device, when I saw I I scratched my head and thought "that's terrible!" and was hoping for some sort of event / notification process that I could hook into, like an event fired by the bluetooth socket when new data is available... but I couldn't find anything like that... (Cont'd)

Comment: ... I installed "System Monitor Lite" which helps see what's going on with CPU / Memory etc.  and I was really surprised to see that even with that loop of code running constantly in the background and with ALL the other bits and pieces running on my phone only one CPU core on the phone was active and it was running at 5%. Strange, if I wrote code which had a thread running in an infinite loop on my PC it would chew up a huge percentage of CPU! I guess for now I'll leave things be but am planning on dropping in a SystemClock.sleep(xxx) when I get further along. (cont'd)

Comment: ... thank you so much for replying and your thoughts, really helps a lot to bounce these things around with someone, hope you have a great weekend :-)

Comment: I am glad that I could help. I recommend visiting Udacity.com site. There is a great course from Google "Developing Android Apps" . Video materials are for free.